# The fastest way to reduce video file size with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

There are several big video files(.mp4) and I want to reduce the size of them to at least half or even less in cost of losing quality, but I want to do this in the fastest way.

I've tried with `libx265` or `libx264`, the output quality is pretty good but it cost too much time. I want to do this faster and **I CAN accept a relatively lower quality**. Is there any method to do this?

Comment: _Fastest_ is probably very dependent on what hardware you're using.  In particular, whether you have GPU codec support and/or CPU features to accelerate video encoding.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the preset modifier to get a faster rendering time as mentioned [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264):

- use something like,

  ```
  -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 -preset ultrafast
  ```
- adjust `crf` value according to your preference and it will change the video quality (18-24 will preserve the input video quality).
- Rendering time is totally adjustable with the `-preset` modifier.

Comment: Looks good. For that +1 could you modify the example code line to include the invocation of `ffmpeg` too, please (so we can see examples of where the input and output files would go, etc.)

Comment: @roaima Here is some code that I hope helps. #!/bin/bash
#
# Reduce mp4 to 480i resolution and reduce size considerably
#
[ ! $1 ] && {
echo -e "Error!! No filename given."; exit 1; } || echo -e "Searching for $1"
ffmpeg -i $1 -s hd480 -strict -2  $1Small.mp4

Comment: It needs to go [into your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/716161/edit). As code (select the code block and hit the `{}` button). Comments can - and do - get deleted

Comment: Thank you! Unlike some other snippets, this one utilizes M1 at 92% (user), and speed raised alot.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code that I hope helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reduce mp4 to 480i resolution and reduce size considerably

[ ! "$1" ] && {
echo -e "Error!! No filename given."; exit 1; } || echo -e "Searching for $1"
ffmpeg -i "$1" -s hd480 -strict -2  "$1"Small.mp4
```

Comment: Can you explain what makes this fast?  Code-only answers have low education value compared to those that properly explain why the code is the way it is.

Comment: I never said it was fast. @Toby Speight

Comment: In that case, you're not answering the question, which is specifically about performing the transcoding quickly.

Comment: I enjoy helping others. I am not perfect, but that is ok by me. @Toby Speight